Resume Tips After Running My Own Business?
How to tackle this?: after running my own business for years, I’m looking to get back into the job market. I’ve learned a ton of transferable skills, especially with project planning and managing tough situations. But I’m worried that if I put all that on my resume, recruiters might think I’m overqualified or just want to be in charge. The thing is, I love working in teams and collaborating, not leading everything. Any tips on how I can highlight these skills without scaring recruiters off?

What type of business did you run?  Because running a consultancy where you are doing projects in conjunction with clients would easily be tweaked to show "teams" and "collaboration".  But business selling things might have to be tweaked in a different way.

Or don't use recruiters and find work through networking.

Resumes are about achievements not jobs. If you ran your own business, it should be trivial to find some things to put on a resume that identify you as someone to be associated with.

In my opinion, this is similar to the question of what do I put on my resume if my job title doesn't match one in the company I am applying for. Ignore the title and focus on what you actually did, showing the skills you used and the successes in applying them.

The difficulty I faced when seeking employment after running my own business was trying to convince the interviewers that I was fully committed to this new career - they thought I'd miss the challenges of self-employment, and become bored with the structured workflow.
In truth, they were right; when I did get a job, I struggled to cope with the (as I saw it) bad management decisions, and the lack of control over my own workload, so this phase of my career didn't last long.
Eventually I was lucky enough to find a consultancy role in a small startup company, which combined the best of both worlds, but I'd suggest you think long & hard about the extent to which you could cope with a more mundane employment - you can omit some of your skills from the resume, but will that get you a job you don't want?

This answer really addresses the risk from the hiring employer's point of view. They would want somebody with the skillset and ability to run their own business, but not be afraid that they will run off when the person is tired of taking orders. That is tough to convey on CV that AI is going to pass/fail before a human will get to review.

You do not need any additional information. Just apply the rules of writing CV's as favorable to you. Please keep in mind that you may have more than one version of CV, each customized for a specific job or job type. Preferably, do not over do it, do not create too many variants of CV's.
A few tips:

do not lie - under any circumstances;
write only what is favorable for you, for that kind of job; omission is allowed;
be succinct, provide only the essential information;
if it has sentences, it is not a CV - that is for the cover letter - if you want to have one, or if it requested;
present yourself in the most favorable light.

For a burger flipper, you might say that in X years you flipped Y number of times with only Z failures. For a manager position, mention how many people answered to you, or how many customers you dealt with - even the "size" of the customers (10 employees vs. 10000 employees). For engineering, present the kind of projects you worked for, and the technologies and skills employed. Etc.

I'm not sure why running your own business would "scare off" recruiters.  Anyone who has tried to do such knows the hardship it is being in business for yourself.  While the Instagramers make it seem easy-peasy most of us know, or can at least imagine, the pain that running a business is.
Your keys to the resume should be the same as anyone else:

Indicate the direction you want to take your career
Indicate how the needs of the company, as they perceive them through a job ad, align with your skills and desires
Indicate supporting evidence that you possess the skills the company is seeking and have a proven track record
Indicate how you can help them in a horizontal way if the need arises.

Perhaps your business beat you up a bit and you are having some negative feelings about yourself.  That is what I am reading into your question.
You do have weaknesses, we all do.  That does not mean you will not be a great fit as a employee for some company.  One thing I would attempt to make clear, is that you will not try and take over the organization.  That you will "know your lane" no matter what kind of position you are hired into.

Don't you think several of those things you list are better suited for a cover letter or explaining/enhancing during an interview?

My point exactly - I can explain it in the interview properly, but when putting on the CV co-founder, business owner it might be a quick NO for a recruiter. So, not sure how to present it in the CV.
